# Update subview's corner radius when Cell's size change

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a VC (`MainVC`), inside hold a property `UICollectionView`. This `CollectionView` has a custom layout (`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`).

I also have a setting, which can change some of this custom layout's property (number of items per page).

Now, inside the `collectionViewCell`, I have an image, which desired to have rounded rect. So I use this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
}
```

However, when I apply the setting, change the custom flow layout, the cell doesn't re-draw and the `drawRect:` never got called => Result: not a rounded rect border for the `imageView`.

What should I do to apply new layout (resize the cell with custom layout) and remain rounded rect for the cell's `imageView`?

Comment: easiest way is to create two sets of custom cells, one with the corner radius, one without, then on reload, flip a switch and load the different cells, this works, but it's a lot of extra code, but it's fail proof, and will get the job done in like 20 mins vs thinking, so don't think, just sub class two cells, then with the left over time, get high and sleep

Comment: @Loxx Lol, I'd like the get high and sleep, but I'm looking for a solution that could optimize the code as much as possible. It's not that I haven't thought about your solution, I just find it doesn't fit me. Enjoy you joint ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯